# httptest ResponseRecorder keeps the old value

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a `handlerAuthentication` function that I need to test:

```golang
func handlerAuthentication(c *gin.Context) {
    session := Session.GetSession(c)
    var login Login
    err := c.BindJSON(&login)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }
    client, err := initClient(c, login)
    fmt.Println("Error: ",err)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("There's an error !")
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"error": ErrorWrongLogin})
        return
    }
    err = (*client).Logout(c)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    session.Set("username", login.Username)
    session.Set("password", login.Password)
    err = session.Save()
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "an error occurred during the save of the session:" + err.Error()})
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Connected")
}
```

To do so,I made this:

```golang
func TestHandlerAuthentication(t *testing.T) {
    UrlOdoo = "https://isi.nc"
    resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
    gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
    c, r := gin.CreateTestContext(resp)

    r.POST("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        handlerAuthentication(c)
    })

    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer ctrl.Finish()

    Odoo = OdooRPC{createMockOdooClient}
    client = mock_odoorpc.NewMockOdooClient(ctrl)
    client.EXPECT().Authenticate(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), invalidUsername, invalidPassword).AnyTimes().Return(fmt.Errorf("invalid login"))
    client.EXPECT().Authenticate(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), validUsername, validPassword).AnyTimes().Return(nil)
    client.EXPECT().Logout(gomock.Any()).AnyTimes().Return(nil)

    session = mock_session.NewMockSession(ctrl)
    Session = SessionGetter{createMockSession}
    session.EXPECT().Set("username", validUsername).AnyTimes().Return()
    session.EXPECT().Set("password", validPassword).AnyTimes().Return()
    session.EXPECT().Save().AnyTimes().Return(nil)

    for name, test := range map[string]struct {
        input   Login
        want    int
    }{
        "valid login": {
            input: Login{
                Username: validUsername,
                Password: validPassword,
            },
            want: 200,
        },
        "invalid login": {
            input: Login{
                Username: invalidUsername,
                Password: invalidPassword,
            },
            want: 401,
        },
    } {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            body, _ := json.Marshal(test.input)
            c.Request, _ = http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/test", strings.NewReader(string(body)))
            r.ServeHTTP(resp, c.Request)
            assert.Equal(t, test.want, resp.Code)
            resp.Flush()
        })
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that if I do the tests one by (`valid login` and `invalid login`), they all pass, but when I do the two tests at the same time, the second test fails.
Here's an exemple of execution of the two tests at the same time:

```
=== RUN   TestHandlerAuthentication
=== RUN   TestHandlerAuthentication/valid_login
Error:  <nil> //No error, so resp.Code should be equal to 200
=== RUN   TestHandlerAuthentication/invalid_login
Error:  invalid login //Error, so resp.Code should be equal to 401
There's an error !
    main_test.go:394: 
            Error Trace:    main_test.go:394
            Error:          Not equal: 
                            expected: 401
                            actual  : 200
            Test:           TestHandlerAuthentication/invalid_login
--- FAIL: TestHandlerAuthentication (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestHandlerAuthentication/valid_login (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestHandlerAuthentication/invalid_login (0.00s)


Expected :401
Actual   :200
```

As expected, an error occured when the login is invalid, but the resp.Code is still 200.
And if I do the `invalid login` test first, the resp.Code will still be 401.

Is it happening because the tests are parallelized and the httptest ResponseRecorder doesn't work in parallel ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think `httptest.ResponseRecorder` is reusable; you should initialize it in each testcase.

Comment: Thank you, I initialize it inside the  `t.Run(name,func(t *testing.T)` function and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [leaf bebop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9143962/leaf-bebop)

I needed to initialize a new `httptest.ResponseRecorder` for each test.
To do so, I move the initialisation to the `t.Run(name,func(t *testing.T)` function:

```golang
func TestHandlerAuthentication(t *testing.T) {
    UrlOdoo = "https://isi.nc"

    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer ctrl.Finish()

    Odoo = OdooRPC{createMockOdooClient}
    client = mock_odoorpc.NewMockOdooClient(ctrl)
    client.EXPECT().Authenticate(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), invalidUsername, invalidPassword).AnyTimes().Return(fmt.Errorf("invalid login"))
    client.EXPECT().Authenticate(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), validUsername, validPassword).AnyTimes().Return(nil)
    client.EXPECT().Logout(gomock.Any()).AnyTimes().Return(nil)

    session = mock_session.NewMockSession(ctrl)
    Session = SessionGetter{createMockSession}
    session.EXPECT().Set("username", validUsername).AnyTimes().Return()
    session.EXPECT().Set("password", validPassword).AnyTimes().Return()
    session.EXPECT().Save().AnyTimes().Return(nil)

    for name, test := range map[string]struct {
        input Login
        want  int
    }{
        "valid login": {
            input: Login{
                Username: validUsername,
                Password: validPassword,
            },
            want: 200,
        },
        "invalid login": {
            input: Login{
                Username: invalidUsername,
                Password: invalidPassword,
            },
            want: 401,
        },
    } {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
            gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
            c, r := gin.CreateTestContext(resp)

            r.POST("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
                handlerAuthentication(c)
            })

            body, _ := json.Marshal(test.input)
            c.Request, _ = http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/test", strings.NewReader(string(body)))
            r.ServeHTTP(resp, c.Request)
            assert.Equal(t, test.want, resp.Code)
        })
    }
}
```